# is sizeof(T*) for every T the same?

Tags: c, sizeof

Is the value returned by `sizeof(T*)` for every `T` the same?

Can a `sizeof(void*)` be a different size than an arbitrary `sizeof(T*)`?

Comment: No, and yes, respectively.  There have been machines (none are popular today) where type `char *` was bigger than type `int *`.  Under MS-DOS, it was common for data pointers and function pointers to have different sizes.  Today, there are variants on 64-bit programming models which use slightly different addressing to not waste bits on full 64-bit addresses everywhere.

Comment: Pointers to functions is also a problematic area, where pointers to function can be different from other pointers (including different sizes).

Comment: See also [Question 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A common example with select modern architectures is that the size of a `void *` differs from the size of a pointer to a function.